# C++: How to read csv file with newline and comma delimited

Tags: c++, csv, file

I'm aware that this question has been asked.
But I couldn't find a solution for my case.
I have a file as follow:

```
4 
apple,banana,cat,donkey
```

My desired output is this:

```
apple|banana|cat|donkey|
```

And my code:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("file1.txt");

int num;
string line;
infile >> num;
infile >> line;
size_t pos = 0;
vector<string>data;
string a;
while ((pos = line.find(",")) != string::npos){
   a = line.substr(0, pos);
   data.push_back(a);
   line.erase(0, pos + (",".length()));
}
for (auto x: data)
   cout << x << "|";
```

By finding comma, I managed to read first 3 items, but failed to read the last one (donkey). How can I detect the newline with a similar method, preferably without getline? It failed when I use newline as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Add the condition after the loop

```
if (!line.empty())
  data.push_back(line);
```

This will add the tail after the last comma to the vector.

New line is not placed at the end of the line when you read a string from an input stream like `ifile >> line;`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have misunderstood the concept , now I'm clear.